# Opera doesn't show up in the system Share menu on Android 13

Tags: android-13, share-menu, opera-browser

I'm using Xiaomi Redmi Note 10 Pro (M2101K6G) with Android 13 and MIUI 14. For some reason Opera for Android ([Opera browser with AI](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.browser)) doesn't show up in the standard system Share menu, which is pretty annoying, since launching Opera and manually pasting the URL takes time. Interestingly enough, Opera does show up in the "Open with" dialog for .html files in a file manager. Is it a standard behavior for Opera on Android or is it just me and my device?